# How to improve CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo performance

Tags: macos, performance, quartz-2d

The documentation for `CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo` says

> Generating the dictionaries for system windows is a relatively expensive operation. As always, you should profile your code and adjust your usage of this function appropriately for your needs.

My question is how can I "adjust" my use of this function?   For a code automation process I frequently need to check what window is frontmost among those of document or modal level.  That is, I call `CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo`, ignore the windows that belong to other processes or have levels that I don't care about, and identify the first window that remains.

If there were a way to ask for information about just the windows owned by my process, say, that would be nice, but I see no way to do that.  Or if there were a way to be notified when my windows change.  I could watch for Carbon Events when windows are hidden or shown, but of course that is a deprecated technology.

Comment: You haven't really said what it is you're doing. How are you actually using the function?

Comment: @uchuugaka, I added a sentence to my question, does that answer your question?

Comment: Do either `-[NSApplication orderedWindows]` or `+[NSWindow windowNumbersWithOptions:]` combined with `-[NSApplication windowWithWindowNumber:]` work better for your purposes? The first has the caveat that it ignores certain kinds of windows. I don't know if either is faster than `CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo()`.

Comment: @KenThomases, thanks, I was not aware of those functions.  I have some Carbon windows (I know, shame on me) so `-[NSApplication orderedWindows]` wouldn't see them, but I'm not sure about `+[NSWindow windowNumbersWithOptions:]`.  I'll have to give it a try.

Comment: Carbon windows may be visible to Cocoa. They are not as segregated as you might think. Worth a try, anyway.

Comment: @KenThomases, `+[NSWindow windowNumbersWithOptions:]` does work with Carbon windows, and seems to be at least an order of magnitude faster than `CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo`.  Thanks!  If you'd like to write that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `[NSWindow windowNumbersWithOptions:0]` to get the window numbers of just the current application's windows (on the active space) in z-order.